# Can local workstations connect to a Azure-hosted domain controller over the internet?

Tags: azure, domaincontroller

Can I migrate my domain into Azure and still allow local workstations to join that domain? I currently have a setup of 7 workstations and 1 server. I'd like to move the server into Azure. It's the domain controller, DNS, AD, and file server. Is my scenario possible? I would just like to make it seem as if the workstation doesn't know the difference other than its now connecting to a different server. The end user would still work as they used to as well. I've found a lot of info on joining other Azure VMs to a Azure-hosted domain controller, but nothing like I'm looking for. It's for a small business setup and I'm new to Azure, but instead of replacing aging server hardware, I'd rather move it to the cloud. If only certain services are possible, that's fine, the minimum requirement would be just being able to setup a domain. I can setup file services through other methods if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Description of support boundaries for Active Directory over NAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978772)

The Microsoft statement regarding Active Directory over NAT is:

- Active Directory over NAT has not been tested by Microsoft.
- We do not recommend Active Directory over NAT.
- Support for issues related to
  Active Directory over NAT will be very limited and will reach the
  bounds of commercially reasonable efforts very quickly.

The problem is that as part of the connection sequence the  AD server will send its local IP Address for the client to connect to, so the client will attempt to connect to the address behind NAT.

The only way you can connect a client to an AD VM is to go through a virtual network. So as long as you had a site to site VPN your clients wouldn't notice any difference.